# How to create a transparent label inside a progress bar with custom tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to create a label inside a progress bar while still showing the progress widget underneath

here is my code:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk

window = ctk.CTk()

prog_num = ctk.IntVar(value=100)
prog_str = ctk.StringVar(value='100/100')

prog_frm = ctk.CTkFrame(window)
prog_pbr = ctk.CTkProgressBar(prog_frm,
                              variable=prog_num,
                              height=15,
                              progress_color='#fa2844')

prog_lbl = ctk.CTkLabel(prog_pbr, textvariable=prog_str, fg_color='transparent')

prog_pbr.pack(fill='x')
prog_lbl.place(rely=0.5, relx=0, anchor='w')
prog_frm.pack(fill='x')

window.mainloop()
```

[code output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wie45.png)

even thought he fg_color is set to transparent it still shows some sort of label background
The only solutions ive found only work for regular tkinter

Comment: Tkinter simply does not support transparent widgets.  The 'transparent' option in customtkinter is a shortcut for specifying the same color as the underlying (parent) widget's color, but the widget itself is still opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you study the code of `customtkinter`, you will find that `CTkProgressBar` is a `Canvas` widget inside a `Frame` widget.  So you can draw the required transparent text inside the `Canvas` widget using `Canvas.create_text()`.

Below is an example using a custom `CTkProgressBar` that show the progress text at the center of the bar:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

class MyProgressBar(ctk.CTkProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # create the text item in the internal canvas
        self._canvas.create_text(0, 0, text=self._variable.get(), fill="yellow",
                                 font=('Arial', 10), anchor="c", tags="progress_text")

    # override function to move the progress text at the center of the internal canvas
    def _update_dimensions_event(self, event):
        super()._update_dimensions_event(event)
        self._canvas.coords("progress_text", event.width/2, event.height/2)

    # override function to update the progress text whenever new value is set
    def set(self, val, **kwargs):
        super().set(val, **kwargs)
        self._canvas.itemconfigure("progress_text", text=int(val*100))


window = ctk.CTk()

prog_frm = ctk.CTkFrame(window)

prog_num = ctk.IntVar(value=50)
# create the custom progress bar
prog_pbr = MyProgressBar(prog_frm,
                         variable=prog_num,
                         height=25,
                         progress_color='#fa2844')
prog_pbr.pack(fill='x', padx=50, pady=20)
prog_frm.pack(fill='x')

# loop to update the bar for demonstration
def update(val=0.0):
    prog_pbr.set(val)
    window.after(100, update, (val+0.01)%1)

update()

window.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]